# Get lookup item url in Display Template using JS

Tags: display-template

as we all know, we can use managed properties in display templates like this:

```
ctx.CurrentItem.myLookupField
```

Let's say myLookupField is actually a lookup field (duh). How would I get the ID or, even better, the absolute url to the lookup item? I have used SP manager to look into the fields array of CurrentItem but found nothing so far.